# query for timestamp in neo4j

Tags: timestamp, neo4j

I have ten nodes with a name and place attribute. I need a cypher query such that each of the nodes have a timestamp ( mostly using time and not date ).
please give me a sample code, where a node is created with the name, place and time attribute.
also a query to check the difference between these nodes

Comment: I think we need more info to give a good answer. Can you give us some sample data and example results? Ideally on console.neo4j.org

Comment: CREATE (_0 { name : 'amrita', age :'22', bornTime : '100000000' }) 
CREATE (_1 { name : 'Krishna', age :'16', bornTime : '100020000' }) 
CREATE (_2 { name : 'vidya', age :'47', bornTime : '100040000' }) 
CREATE (_3 { name : 'kanak', age :'50', bornTime : '100060000' }) 
CREATE (_10 { name : 'arvind', age :'28', bornTime : '101800000' }) 
CREATE _0-[:`KNOWS`]->_1 
CREATE _0-[:`KNOWS`]->_2 
this is wat i have created so far. can u tell if the way i have given the time can considered a timestamp?
and also how should i retrieve the nodes that are created after the time 10:05?